# Align ActionBar Navigation Tab icons above the tab text?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

The app has an ActionBar, and the ActionBar has Navigation Tabs, each containing text. I need to add icons to the tabs, in addition to the text.

I have added the icons using `ActionBar.Tab.setIcon(drawable)` successfully, but the icon shows to the left of the tab text.

How do I move the tab icon so it is ABOVE the navigation tab text?

(I'm using ActionBarSherlock, but figure the solution to this will work across native and ABS implementations)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set a custom view to each tab.

https://gist.github.com/3167287

**PropositionListActivity.java**

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class PropositionListActivity extends SherlockActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

        setContentView(R.layout.proposition_list);

        getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        createTab(R.layout.tab_to_opine, R.id.tab_to_opine_title, "Vou Opinar");
        createTab(R.layout.tab_opined, R.id.tab_opined_title, "Já Opinei");
        createTab(R.layout.tab_feedback, R.id.tab_feedback_title, "Feedback");
    }

    public void createTab(int view, int titleView, String title) {
        ActionBar.Tab tab = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        tab.setCustomView(view);
        getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab);

        ((TextView) findViewById(titleView)).setText(title);
    }
}
```

**tab_to_opine.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tab_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/tab_to_opine"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tab_to_opine_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It would be nice if you posted the code here in case the link breaks.

Comment: Done, Joony. Stack Overflow isn't a perfect placeholder for more than a couple lines of code, so I still kept the gist link.

Comment: Here's a link to vogella.com where he shows how to add a custom view to an actionbar without actionBarSherlock. http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidActionBar/article.html#menu_customviews

Answer (score 1):

In the styles.xml file you can add an 
`<item name="android:drawableTop">@drawable/your_image.</item>` 
This will work if you want all of the images to be the same across the top. I don't quite know how to do this for tabs that use different images yet unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

its very simple just add android:drawableTop="@drawable/your_image" to your Textview and remove the ImageView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

`<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tab_to_opine_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/your_image" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```